# Why is my .ssh/config file not readable?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, permission, ssh

I am trying to edit my `ssh/config` file, but when I type `emacs ~/.ssh/config` into Terminal, it says that the file is not readable and will not save my edits. When I try to overwrite, it says permission is denied. Why is this happening?

`ls -la ~/.ssh/config` returns

```
-rw------- 1 root staff 1141 Jul 17 14:30 /Users/firestarter/.ssh/config
```

It says permission denied when I try to `cat` it

Comment: That indicates the config file is owned by root, but it should be owned by your account. Try `sudo chown firestarter Users/firestarter/.ssh/config`. Depending on what happened, there may be other files (or maybe the entire .ssh directory) owned by root, and those'll need to be fixed similarly. BTW, this is a is good example of why you shouldn't just use `sudo` without understanding what's going on -- editing the file under `sudo` is probably what caused this in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your config file got copied by somebody else. Log in as an admin user if you ain't one already and run

```bsh
sudo chown firestarter /Users/firestarter/.ssh /Users/firestarter/.ssh/*
sudo chmod 700 /Users/firestarter/.ssh
```